# Which enantiomer of 3-Chloro-2-pentanol is this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

[image: Given Molecule]

I think that there is a chiral centers at $C_2$ and at $C_3$ (Numbering starting such that the carbon with hydroxy attached is number 2.

Then, for $C_2$:

1. Priority would be: OH > $C_3$ > $C_1$ > H
2. This makes it clockwise, so R

Then, for for $C_2$:

1. Priority would be: Cl > $C_2$ > $C_4$ > H
2. This makes it anticlock wise, so S

Therefore, the molecule becomes 2R, 3S 3-Chloro-2-pentanol.

Is this correct?

Comment: Clockwise/counterclockwise change their meaning depending on whether the H is facing towards you or away.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I know, however here I do not have any information about the H? Do I?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I just realised, that in $C_2$, H is actually, at the front if CH3 is at the back. Then, I would have to switch them up, and it would actually become 2S, 3S. Is this correct?

Comment: Now that looks correct to me.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks

Comment: @NaitikMundra A program like ChemDraw ([sample page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html)) can provide a check: draw the structure, mark them by the lasso, use the structure2name function (bottom row of the icons, the fourth counting from the right hand side). *But:* don't rely blindly on a computer program (which may include an [accidental] error of implementing the CIP rules, and nomenclature in general) -- continue your training to be able to apply the rules by yourself.

Comment: @NaitikMundra The site's [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812) actually compiled reference material about chemical nomenclature, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks! The answer was in front of me and I never noticed.